# Download Image and show Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, async-await

I would like to download images in Xamarin and show it but I have an error says

> "cannot await void"

on the line;

```
var imageBytes = await webClient.DownloadDataAsync(url);
```

Here is the code:

```
public async void DownloadImages()
{
     var webClient = new WebClient();
     var url = new Uri("myurl.jpg");

     var imageBytes  =  await webClient.DownloadDataAsync(url);

     if (imageBytes != null && imageBytes.Length > 0)
     {
         GridRectangleImage.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(imageBytes));
     }        
}
```

Comment: Because the method [WebClient.DownloadDataAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloaddataasync?view=netframework-4.8) is **not** awaitable (as documented)

Comment: Maybe you are looking for [WebClient.DownloadDataTaskAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloaddatataskasync?view=netframework-4.8)? You should really read the docs.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [DownloadDataAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloaddataasync?view=netframework-4.8): when the download completes, the `DownloadDataCompleted` event is raised. The downloaded data is available in the `Result` property.:

```
public async void DownloadImages()
{
    var webClient = new WebClient();
    var url = new Uri("myurl.jpg");

    webClient.DownloadDataAsync(url);

    webClient.DownloadDataCompleted += WebClient_DownloadDataCompleted;
}

private void WebClient_DownloadDataCompleted(object sender, DownloadDataCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var imageBytes = e.Result;

    if (imageBytes != null && imageBytes.Length > 0)
    {
        GridRectangleImage.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(imageBytes));
    }
}
```

If you use [DownloadDataTaskAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloaddatataskasync?view=netframework-4.8), the `Result` property on the task object returns a Byte array containing the downloaded resource:

```
public async void DownloadImages()
{
    var webClient = new WebClient();
    var url = new Uri("myurl.jpg");

    var imageBytes = await webClient.DownloadDataTaskAsync(url);

    if (imageBytes != null && imageBytes.Length > 0)
    {
        GridRectangleImage.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(imageBytes));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Hugokis

Follow these step,To Download Image and show Xamarin

**Step 1:-** Create Xamarin Project.

**step 2:-** Add Xamarin Support v7 AppCompat Library.
            Add a reference **Android.Support.v7. AppCompat** using NuGet Package Manager

**step 3:-** Add Code in app.xaml file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>  
<resources>  
  <style name="MyTheme" parent="MyTheme.Base">  
  </style>  
  <!--Base theme applied no matter what API-->  
  <style name="MyTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">  
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>  
    <!--We will be using the toolbar so no need to show ActionBar-->  
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>  
    <!--Set theme color from http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html#color-co-->  
    <!--Color Primary is used for default action bar backround-->  
    <item name="colorPrimary">#009688</item>  
    <!--Color Primary Dark is use for status bar-->  
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#1976D2</item>  
    <!--ColorAccent is used as the default value for   
    ColorControlActivat1ed which is used to tint widgts-->  
    <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>  
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">#FF4081</item>  
    <!--You can also set ColorControlNormal ColorControlActivated   
      ColorControlHihglight colorSwitchThumbNormal.-->  
  </style>  
</resources>
```

**step 4:-** Add a new folder to the Resources Folder with name values-v21. Similarly, add a new XAML file inside values-v21 folder - style.xml and add the following code.

**Xaml Code :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>  
<resources>  
  <!--  
  Base Application theme for API 21+. this theme   
  replaces MyTheme from res/style.xml on API 21+ devices-->  
  <style name="MyTheme" parent="MyTheme.Base">  
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>  
    <item name="android:windowAllowEnterTransitionOverlap">true</item>  
    <item name="android:windowAllowReturnTransitionOverlap">true</item>  
    <item name="android:windowSharedElementEnterTransition">@android:transition/move</item>  
    <item name="android:windowSharedElementExitTransition">@android:transition/move</item>  
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>  
  </style>  
</resources>
```

**step 5:-** Writing DownloadImageFromUrl Class

**C# Code**

```
using System;  
using System.Collections.Generic;  
using System.Linq;  
using System.Text;  
using Android.App;  
using Android.Content;  
using Android.Graphics.Drawables;  
using Android.OS;  
using Android.Runtime;  
using Android.Views;  
using Android.Widget;  
using Java.IO;  
using Java.Net;  
namespace SaveWithProgress  
{  
    public class DownloadImageFromUrl : AsyncTask<string, string, string>  
    {  
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;  
        private ImageView imgView;  
        private Context context;  
        public DownloadImageFromUrl(Context context, ImageView imgView)  
        {  
            this.context = context;  
            this.imgView = imgView;  
        }  
        protected override void OnPreExecute()  
        {  
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);  
            pDialog.SetMessage("Downloading file. Please wait...");  
            pDialog.Indeterminate = false;  
            pDialog.Max = 100;  
            pDialog.SetProgressStyle(ProgressDialogStyle.Horizontal);  
            pDialog.SetCancelable(true);  
            pDialog.Show();  
            base.OnPreExecute();  
        }  
        protected override void OnProgressUpdate(params string[] values)  
        {  
            base.OnProgressUpdate(values);  
            pDialog.SetProgressNumberFormat(values[0]);  
            pDialog.Progress = int.Parse(values[0]);  
        }  
        protected override void OnPostExecute(string result)  
        {  
            string strongPath = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.Path;  
            string filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(strongPath, "download.jpg");  
            pDialog.Dismiss();  
            imgView.SetImageDrawable(Drawable.CreateFromPath(filePath));  
        }  
        protected override string RunInBackground(params string[] @params)  
        {  
            string strongPath = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.Path;  
            string filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(strongPath, "download.jpg");  
            int count;  
            try  
            {  
                URL url = new URL(@params[0]);  
                URLConnection connection = url.OpenConnection();  
                connection.Connect();  
                int LengthOfFile = connection.ContentLength;  
                InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.OpenStream(), LengthOfFile);  
                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(filePath);  
                byte[] data = new byte[1024];  
                long total = 0;  
                while ((count = input.Read(data)) != -1 )  
                {  
                    total += count;  
                    PublishProgress(""+(int)((total / 100) / LengthOfFile));  
                    output.Write(data, 0, count);  
                }  
                output.Flush();  
                output.Close();  
                input.Close();  
            }  
            catch (Exception e)  
            {  
            }  
            return null;  
        }  
    }  
}
```

**step 6:-** Main Layout
Open Solution Explorer-> Project Name-> Resources-> Layout-> Main.axml. Open this main layout file and add the following code.

**Xaml Code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"  
    android:orientation="vertical"  
    android:layout_width="match_parent"  
    android:layout_height="match_parent">  
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar  
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"  
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"  
        android:layout_width="match_parent"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"  
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"  
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"  
        local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />  
    <Button  
        android:text="Download Image"  
        android:layout_width="match_parent"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:id="@+id/btnDownload" />  
    <ImageView  
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"  
        android:layout_width="match_parent"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:id="@+id/imageView" />  
</LinearLayout>
```

**step 7:**-Main Activity Class
**C# Code:**

```
using Android.App;  
using Android.Widget;  
using Android.OS;  
using Android.Support.V7.App;  
namespace SaveWithProgress  
{  
    [Activity(Label = "SaveWithProgress", MainLauncher = true , Theme ="@style/MyTheme")]  
    public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity  
    {  
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  
        {  
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);  
            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource  
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);  
            var btnDownload = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnDownload);  
            var imageView = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView);  
            btnDownload.Click += delegate   
            {  
                DownloadImageFromUrl download = new DownloadImageFromUrl(this, imageView);  
                download.Execute("http://www.qygjxz.com/data/out/244/4304228-wallpaper-phone-hd.jpg");  
            };  
        }  
    }  
}
```

**step 8:-** Permission from Device

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />  
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

I hope above code will be useful for you.

Thank you.